# Issue when you set a node to .visible = false, its child nodes are no longer visible

Tags: three.js, model-viewer

I have a problem with Model Viewer with a specific .glb model:

Basically, I have a .glb file that has a node tree with multiple elements. But for this particular example, I will try to resume it on only 1 primary node, with only 1 secondary node.

The thing is, inside the node tree, if I deselect the parent node, its "visible" attribute becomes "false" and automatically, its child node also becomes invisible no matter what it has as "visible". attribute. So my question is, is there a way to make them independent of each other? My idea would be something like what we have at: https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ where unchecking the parent elements keeps the child elements visible.

What could be generating this behavior? It only happens with some glb files, not all. How would I know which part of the code is doing this validation to show or not show the children of an invisible parent node?

Thank you

I have tried to check/uncheck its child node when its parent is invisible just to check if that was just a bug on the library, but seems like even in that scenario, it won't be visible. So, I would assume that if the parent element is disabled, its childs won't show up no matter what.

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific. First, what is "Model Viewer"? Second, this kind of visibility chaining/grouping seems correct. If a parent node is invisible, neither it nor its children should be added to the list of render-able items. To get the kind of effect you want, you have to decouple the render list generation from the scene tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the material to invisible using:

```js
myobj.material.visible = false
```

However, that can affect other objects as well in case of sharing materials, which you can circumvent by cloning the material first:

```js
if( myobj.material ){
  if( !myobj.material.clone ){
    myobj.material = myobj.material.clone()
    myobj.material.clone = true
  }
  myobj.material.visible = false
}
```